# Computer not powering on, only short PSU fan spin and short GPU LEDs powering on

Tags: cpu, power-supply, fan

I've replaced my CPU fan on my desktop PC yesterday and got it to a point where it was working fine afterwards. Now I have just moved the desktop from the floor back to its location and it won't power on. I've moved it back to the floor where I could open it, and I observed that when powering on the PC, sometimes the PSU fan spins for a split second and the GPU LED blinks for a split second, but then both turn off again and nothing happens. Again I did not really change anything on the inside of the PC after I got it working yesterday.

Does anyone have an idea what could be the cause or how to investigate further what could be the cause?

Comment: It could be that some cable was accidentally dislodged. All you would need to do is make sure that they are all seated properly. Was it just the fan that you replaced or the whole heatsink? Did you take any anti-static precautions?

Comment: What are the make and model and/or CPU and motherboard?  The reason I ask is that I've seen this exact error on two systems with different problems.  One was a  HP 6400MT(never did find that cause here) and the other was an older AMD/Gigabyte that after re-seating CPU and memory worked fine.

Comment: @AndrewMorton the cables are all attached. I replaced the whole heatsink. I grounded myself several times during replacement, but I did not wear anything that continuously grounds myself during the replacement.

Comment: I got it to work now by blowing on the PSU cable connection and just continuing to try it, but it seems very inconsistent and I'm not sure if it will power on the next time I'll try it, but I guess none of the hardware pieces can be damaged if it does occasionally power up correctly?

Comment: @GB-AE7OO CPU is Intel Core i5 3550, mainboard is ASRock B75 Pro3. I also recently added an additional memory bank if this might be associated, I doubt it though.

Comment: @LukasBach With the power supply switched off, disconnect that cable that you were blowing on. Gently tug at each wire in the connector - they should not come out. Have a look inside the connectors for any inconsistencies, for example a connector that has been crushed. Examine the corresponding connector on the motherboard, in case it is damaged. A bright light and a magnifying glass could be useful.

Comment: "also recently added an additional memory bank " I highly suggest removing the added memory sticks and checking again. Incorrectly seated memory may create this issue.

Comment: I would remove and replace all cables and memory.  I would not worry about the CPU unless you have removed the heat sink(or more) in a period close to the failure.

Comment: @NatsuKage Ok I'll try that. But again, since the PC still managed to power up somehow, how could the memore be the fault then?

Comment: @GB-AE7OO What do you mean by replace the cables? Most of them belong to the PSU, do you suggest replacing the PSU?

Comment: @Lukas Bach    Some PCs will go into a boot failure with RAM sticks defective. I've had this recently on one of my computers.  Try re-seating them or removing them individually to test if one is defective/badly inserted.

Comment: Sorry, was not clear.  disconnect each cable and then re-seat it.  Unless have removed the CPU heatsink within lets say a couple of days of the error, there is no reason to mess with it.